# CSS selector for numbered class/id

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-selectors

I have the following situation:

```
<div id="myMenu">
   <div id="menu0">stuffs</div>
   <div id="menu1">stuffs</div>
   <div id="menu2">stuffs</div>
   ...... and so on
</div>
```

My requirement is to access all div having id `$=menu` inside `myMenu` except `menu0`, as my menu can have like 10 to 15 item so one way is to do:

```
 #myMenu > menu1 {style}
 #myMenu > menu2 {style}
 so on... 15 times
```

but as I have to give same style to all of them , it seems unnecessary , I am looking for CSS selector which will fit correctly for my requirement also having compatible to IE8.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will it always be the first wrapped element that you don't want to style?

Comment: Why dont you add a class to every element you want to style?

Comment: yes david it's always Menu0 
no Der , i can't , it's autogenerated code , i can't add anything in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you always have the `#menu0` element, you can use the *general sibling selector* that is IE8 compliant:

```css
    #menu0 ~ [id^="menu"] {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="myMenu">
   <div id="menu0">stuffs</div>
   <div id="menu1">stuffs</div>
   <div id="menu2">stuffs</div>
</div>
```

or use `classes` (along with `id`s) that would fit better.

Comment: I've added the code snippet so you can see it now :)

Comment: Awesome , it worked , Thanks Andrea. and thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 4):

This css3 rule will get the list without #menu0:

```
div#myMenu > div:not(#menu0)
{
}
```

Alternately, you can use these two:

```
div#myMenu > div
{ 
    /*new values*/ 
}

div#myMenu > div#menu0
{ 
    /*reset with the original values*/ 
}
```

This code will hit all the children divs, then the second rule will override the prior one because it is later in the cascade and reset #menu0 to its original condition.

Comment: OP asked to exclude `#menu0`. You code will style all elements including `#menu0`.

Comment: Ooh, missed that part. I added the css3 :not()

Comment: @Vivek I made a small change that might handle it better.

Comment: Due to the partial/missing support of IE8 for the :not pseudo class I would suggest to use a css reset like in this answer.

Comment: yes Overridding is one good way , i will try this if i can't find anything better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use class but also you can:

```css
#myMenu div[id^="menu"]:not(#menu0) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myMenu">
  <div id="menu0">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu1">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu2">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu3">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu4">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu5">stuffs</div>
</div>
```

This one selects all `id` which start with word 'menu' and is child of element with id `#myMenu` but exclude element with id `#menu0`

After comment for older browsers e.g. ie8 you can use:

```css
#myMenu div[id^="menu"] {
  color: red;
}
#myMenu #menu0 {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myMenu">
  <div id="menu0">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu1">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu2">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu3">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu4">stuffs</div>
  <div id="menu5">stuffs</div>
</div>
```

Because id is unique.

Comment: I was suggesting the class usage and the startswith selector... damn u're fast :S :)

Comment: > _except "menu0",_. @Vivek doesn't want to style menu0

Comment: it will select "menu0" too , i don't want menu0 selected.

Comment: I would recommend not using `!important`, and just use specificity:     
`#myMenu #menu0 {
      color: #000;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

add another class:

```
<div id="myMenu">
   <div id="menu0">stuffs</div>
   <div id="menu1" class="sub">stuffs</div>
   <div id="menu2" class="sub">stuffs</div>
   ...... and so on
</div>
```

and select:

```
#myMenu > .sub{ ... }
```

or simplicity

```
#myMenu  .sub{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as implied from the comments to the question, it's always the first child that should not be selected:

```
/* selects all the <div>s with an id beginning with 'menu',
   that follow a <div> with an id beginning with menu, that
   are the direct-children of the element with an id of 'myMenu': */
#myMenu > div[id^=menu] + div[id^=menu] {
    /* css here */
}
```

Or:

```
/* selects all <div> elements that are not the :first-child
   that are direct children of <div id="myMenu">: */
#myMenu > div:not(:first-child)
    /* css here */
}
```

Or:

```
/* selects all <div>s with an id beginning with menu that
   have a previous sibling <div> with an id beginning with
   'menu' that is the direct child of <div id="myMenu">: */
#myMenu > div[id^=menu] ~ div[id^=menu] 
    /* css here */
}
```

Comment: oh this is tricky , will it not select menu0 and is it IE8 compatible.

Comment: It *can't* select the first element (which is why I asked the question, in the comments). Since `#menu0` is the first child (which is excluded by `:not(:first-child)`, and because the first-element can't be matched by a sibling combinator, `+` or `~`). As for IE8 I don't know; I don't have a copy of that to experiment with.

Comment: Thanks David for your quick response.